Is it possible to replace the start destination in Jetpack Compose Navigation without losing the backstack?
I have a NavGraph setup so you can change the start destination while being on another screen entirely (e.g. A is the start destination - I navigate to C and change the start destination to B) - however, this causes the NavGraph to recompose and I end up on the start destination rather than remain on the screen I'm on currently (C in the example).
My preferred behavior would be to remain on C screen, while swapping A for B in the backstack.
Is this possible to setup, since I had the exact same usecase working on fragment navigation?
NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = startDestination) {
composable<A> {}
composable<B> {}
composable<C> {}
}


I think you can use nested navigation for this use case

Not quite sure how nested navigation would help here - if I switched to a different graph when swapping the root screen, I'd still need to manually navigate to the previous screen - which is something I'd like to avoid if possible.
